# onPause() method crashes my app when moving to next screen

Tags: android, onresume, onpause

I am doing a simple app. currently it plays a sound when prompted and works fine but I wanted to stop the sound whenever the screen is locked allowing the user control over when sound it played. So, I found a method that does this but now the app crashes when it tries to move screen(either back or forward)

Here is the method

```
public class Tables1 extends Activity
{
MediaPlayer mysound;
protected boolean active = true;
boolean created;
protected int splashtime = 17000;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tables1);
    mysound=MediaPlayer.create(Tables1.this, R.raw.part1 );
   created = true;
   Log.d("Exercise", "created = true ");

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // when the screen is about to turn off
    if (ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
        mysound.pause();
        mysound.release();
        System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED OFF");
    } else {
        // this is when onPause() is called when the screen state has not changed
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // only when screen turns on
    if (!ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) 
    {

        System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED ON");
    } else {
        // this is when onResume() is called when the screen state has not changed
    }
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}

/*@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{

    super.onDestroy();
    mysound.stop();
    mysound.reset();
    mysound.release();
    created = false;
    mysound = null;
}*/
  public void listen(View view) 
    {

      if(mysound==null)
      {
          mysound=MediaPlayer.create(Tables1.this, R.raw.part2 );
      }
        mysound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mysound) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mysound.stop();
                mysound.reset();
                //mysound.release();
                Log.d("Exercise", "not sound reset ");
            }

        });   
        mysound.start();

    }
  public void Next(View view) 
    {
      if(mysound==null)
      {
          mysound=MediaPlayer.create(Tables1.this, R.raw.part2 );
      }
      if(mysound.isPlaying())
        {
            mysound.stop();
            mysound.reset();
            mysound.release();
            created = false;
            Log.d("Exercise", "sound destroyed ");

        }
      else
      {
          Log.d("Exercise", "not working ");
      }
        mysound.release();
        created = false;
        Log.d("Exercise", "created = false ");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.example","com.example.timestableseasy.Exercise1");
        startActivity(i); 
    }
  public void home(View view) 
    {
      if(mysound==null)
      {
          mysound=MediaPlayer.create(Tables1.this, R.raw.part2 );
      }
      if(created = true)
      {
          if(mysound.isPlaying())
            {
                mysound.stop();
                mysound.reset();

            }
          mysound.release();
      }

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.example","com.example.timestableseasy.Menu2");
        startActivity(i); 
    }


}
```

ScreenReceiver class that is called in this class

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) 
    {
        wasScreenOn = false;
    } 
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) 
    {
        wasScreenOn = true;
    }
}
```

and the log cat

```
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example/com.example.timestableseasy.Tables1}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3159)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:150)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._pause(Native Method)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.pause(MediaPlayer.java:1108)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at com.example.timestableseasy.Tables1.onPause(Tables1.java:37)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5235)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1233)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3145)
06-25 17:11:43.065: E/AndroidRuntime(26822):    ... 12 more
```

line 99 that is complains about is "if(mysound.isPlaying())" but there is a null check before hand.

bascially I want to know why the `onPause()` method messed up the buttons that change screens

Comment: Did you call prepare or prepareAsync? See life cycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: @Zoran no i have not. I didnt think it was needed if i only wanted to pause the sound

Comment: @Zoran when looking at what it does it didnt seem like it effected the on pause method